# mySQL inner join table IF needed

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Hey all i have the following query:

```
SELECT UA.Fname, UA.LName, UA.Title, UA.AccDate, UA.Address1, 
  UA.Address2, UA.City, UA.State, UA.Zip, UA.Email, UA.Phone, 
  LabCaseNum, SpecCaseNum, deadlineDate, CaseDetail, 
  AU.Fname as AuthName, AU.Lname, AU.Phone, AU.Email, AU.Role 
FROM userAccount UA 
INNER JOIN userCase UC ON UA.AccNum = UC.Userlink 
INNER JOIN authPerson AU ON UC.CaseNum = AU.UserCase 
WHERE UC.CaseNum = 7903579800;
```

Which works just fine **IF there is data in the AU table**. However, no records return if there are none in the **AU** table *even though there's always data in the UC and UA tables* to be had.

How can i format the query above to ignore the **AU** table if there is no data to be gathered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using a [LEFT JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_joins) on that table:

```
SELECT UA.Fname, UA.LName, UA.Title, UA.AccDate, UA.Address1, 
  UA.Address2, UA.City, UA.State, UA.Zip, UA.Email, UA.Phone, 
  LabCaseNum, SpecCaseNum, deadlineDate, CaseDetail, 
  AU.Fname as AuthName, AU.Lname, AU.Phone, AU.Email, AU.Role 
FROM userAccount UA 
INNER JOIN userCase UC ON UA.AccNum = UC.Userlink 
LEFT JOIN authPerson AU ON UC.CaseNum = AU.UserCase 
WHERE UC.CaseNum = 7903579800;
```

This will return all rows from the other tables `UA` and `UC` and it will return `null` for the `AU` rows if there is not a matching `UserCase` in that table.

Answer (score 1):

Try a LEFT OUTER JOIN ON AU.  This returns all rows from the first tables weather AU has data or not.  If no AU data, then nulls are returned for the AU Fields

```
SELECT UA.Fname, UA.LName, UA.Title, UA.AccDate, UA.Address1, 
  UA.Address2, UA.City, UA.State, UA.Zip, UA.Email, UA.Phone, 
  LabCaseNum, SpecCaseNum, deadlineDate, CaseDetail, 
  AU.Fname as AuthName, AU.Lname, AU.Phone, AU.Email, AU.Role 
FROM userAccount UA 
INNER JOIN userCase UC ON UA.AccNum = UC.Userlink 
LEFT OUTER JOIN authPerson AU ON UC.CaseNum = AU.UserCase 
WHERE UC.CaseNum = 7903579800;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for contributing to my answers.

Comment: @StealthRT...no problem :)